# Entity Framework optimization when using transactions

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I want to save NUnit local tests in a mysql database hosted in Amazon RDS, and

I'm wrapping up everything in a transaction like so :

```
using (var context = new StDbContext())
         {
            context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
            if (!context.Database.Connection.State.HasFlag(ConnectionState.Open))
            {
               context.Database.Connection.OpenAsync();
            }
            using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
               try
               {
                  var unit_of_work = new UnitOfWork(context);
                  unit_of_work.Sessions.AddModelSession(Model, unit_of_work);
                  context.SaveChanges();

                  transaction.Commit();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                  transaction.Rollback();
                  TestBaseCore.mNLogLoggerService.Error(ex.Message);
               }

            }
         }
```

Is there a better way of optimizing this code, in order to be sure that the connection or the current transaction is still open until all the data it is saved to the database? because when trying to save using this code to a local database everything works perfectly, but when saving to a database hosted by Amazon RDS, the code will crash with no exception.The only difference is the connection string

Comment: "when saving to a database hosted by Amazon RDS, the code will crash with no exception" This sounds like broken code, which is off topic here.

Comment: I'm more interested on a review for it. and possible code optimization. the broke code part I will handle. Maybe there is a better way of writing transactions and I'm missing something

Comment: make your code full async or sync `BeginTransactionAsync` and `SaveChangesAsync` as you've opened an async connection `OpenAsync();`. Also, note that the sent data will be validated by SQL engine and not `EF`, so you should be specific in exceptions for better handling, you will need to include `EF` exceptions like `DbUpdateException`.

Comment: Why don't you await `OpenAsync`? Looks like only on a local db opening the connection is fast enough not to be awaited.